# Passing parameters convention - Ext js 4.2 - Should be an object?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

Sometimes, we need to listen some events in ExtJs to do something. But if we need only one parameter of the list of arguments??

there are some posibilities:

Case 1: set all arguments in the function, to get 'e' param

```
view.on('cellclick', function( table, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts  ){
        me.doSomething( e );
    })
```

Case 2: use 'arguments' with the index needed

```
 view.on('cellclick', function( ){
        me.doSomething( arguments[6] );
    })
```

Case 1, has unused params and case 2 looks like 'hardcode'. Exists any other option to choose when we listen events in ExtJs but only use a few params?

I think that parameters should be pass as an object, but i don't see this on ExtJS.

```
view.on('cellclick', function( options ){
        me.doSomething( options.e );
    })
```

Comment: Personally I would opt for case 1. You may only need `e` today but this approach helps to document what else is being passed to the function. In the future you may decide you need some additional parameters and it will be easier to see what is available as opposed to opening the API documentation, looking up the control, finding the event....

Comment: Agree, i'm using Case 1, When i need specific event i search on Docs, and get full function to work, but what about object notation - Should be nice option to get fast parameters instead of define all of them.

Comment: This is more a code convention question, which comes down to opinion... sure case 1 is nice, but it has its trade offs... what if cellIndex goes away, or gets renamed?  Using the object notation is convenient because it cleans up that long parameter list, but you're still going to have to maintain the documentation or logic that handles the parameter you want to use.